# Gmail is not receiving bulk emails from 1 specific email

Tags: email, outlook, gmail

I am sending emails from an Outlook account(noreply account for bulk emails) to Gmail. But the emails are not being received by the gmail account although the same is received by any other email service (Outlook, hotmail, tempmails).
There is no restriction at my end to restrict to send to Gmail.
When I use my other Outlook account to send to the same Gmail account the email is received.

I am confused as to what could be the reason.

```
> Bulk Email Outlook -> Other than Gmail Account (Working)
> Personal Email Outlook -> Other than Gmail Account (Working)
> Personal Email Outlook -> Gmail Account (Working)
> Bulk Email Outlook -> Gmail Account (Not Working)
```

My program even shows that email is successfully fetched and email sent to it but the email is not received.

The code is working fine and there is nothing specific that I mentioned about Gmail.
Just to mention, I used smtp_port = 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this.

I just added

> smtp_domain = 'DHL.COM'

Write below

> smtp_server = "smtp-nix.dhl.com.pk"
> smtp_port = 25

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Are your personal email account and your bulk email account hosted on the same email server? Do you get an error code back from *Google Mail* which might explain what's going wrong?

*Google Mail* does not accept emails from all servers. Servers may be black-listed after previous spam waves. There are other policy violations which might prevent mails from being accepted.

See the list of [potential Google Mail errors](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?sjid=2581480804760656454-EU).

Comment: I use " smtp-nix@dhl.com.pk " for bulk email and "smtp.office365.com" for personal.
No there's no error from Gmail, there's no activity on Gmail

Comment: sorry it's smtp-nix.dhl.com.pk

Comment: I didn't use TLS. Could that be the reason

Answer (score 0):

### **Suggestion**

I suggest that you check if the bulk email account that you're using has set up either **SPF** or **DKIM** because Google verifies if the email messages sent to personal Gmail account are authenticated (DKIM).

Moreover, the **SPF record** of your domain (`@example.com`) must include references to all email senders for your domain. If you don't, then most likely Google will mark these emails as SPAM and they won't reach Gmail users at all. This also explains why you didn't receive a bounce-back or error message.

I suggest that you check this source for detailed information: [Prevent mail to Gmail users from being blocked or sent to spam](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en&sjid=8065390304696540759-AP)